# Aligning form fields

Tags: html, css, forms

im coding up a HTML form just now and i havinfg a little trouble aligning the comments field to the right of the text fields.

I have 3 text fields uunder each other and i want to have the comments text fields align to the right of them, ive tried floating it it right and then giving it a negative top pargin to move it up inline but the the text i want about saying 'comments' isnt floating with the text fields as it doesnt have a class

is there an easier way to do this?

```
    <style type="text/css">
    ![enter image description here][1]<!--
    body {
background-color: #FFF;
    }

    #form {
width:960px;
background-color:#edf8ff;
height:650px;
    }

    .gezza-form {
width:894px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
    }

    .gezza-field {
width:437px;
height:75px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border: 1px solid #d9e7f1;
    }

    .gezza-comments{
width:437px;
height:300px;
float:right;
margin-top:-80px;
    }

    -->
    </style></head>

    <body>


    <div id="form">

    <form action="" class="gezza-form" method="post" >
    First Name<br />
    <input name="firstname" type="text" class="gezza-field" /><br/>
    Last Name<br />
    <input name="lastname" type="text" class="gezza-field" /><br/>
    Email Address<br />
    <input name="email" type="text" class="gezza-field" />
    Comments<textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" class="gezza-comments" ></textarea>
    </form>


    </div><!-- close form -->
```

Here's what im trying to achieve

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3yO8.png VIEW IMAGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two divs to hold the other elements and arrange them to be side by side.

You could use a table and join cells to hold the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

And if you change .gezza-field to :

```
.gezza-field {
width:437px;
height:75px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border: 1px solid #d9e7f1;
float:left;
}
```